# How to chose a random link on the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am using beautiful soup to get links from a page.
What i would like it to do is select one of the links at random and continue with the rest of the program. Currently it is using all the links and continuing with the rest of the program, however i only want it to choose 1 link.

The the rest of the program will then look at the link and decide if it was good enough for what i want. If it is not good enough it will then go back and click another link. And repeat the processes.

Any idea how you would get it to do this?

This is my current code for looking up the links.

```
import requests
import os.path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import hashlib
import random

max_page = 1
img_limit = 5

def pic_spider(max_pages):
    page = random.randrange(0, max_page)
    pid = page * 40
    pic_good = 1
    while pic_good == 1:
        if page <= max_pages:
            url = 'http://safebooru.org/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=yuri&pid=' + str(pid)
            source_code = requests.get(url)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
            id_list_location = os.path.join(id_save, "ids.txt")
            first_link = soup.findAll('a', id=True, limit=img_limit)
            for link in first_link:
                href = "http://safebooru.org/" + link.get('href')
                picture_id = link.get('id')
                print("Page number = " + str(page + 1))
                print("pid = " + str(pid))
                print("Id = " + picture_id)
                print(href)

                if picture_id in open(id_list_location).read():
                    print("Already Downloaded or Picture checked to be too long")
                else:
                    log_id(picture_id)
                    if ratio_get(href) >= 1.3:
                        print("Picture too long")
                    else:
                        #img_download_link(href, picture_id)
                        print("Ok download")
```

im not really sure how i would do it so any ideas would help me out, if you have any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: If `first_link` is a list, can't you just do `first_link[random_number]`, where the random_number is generated between 0 and the list length? I would imagine `findAll()` returns a list of all elements (it seems BS [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) agree). You could also just use `find` to select one element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am I missing something? Don't you just need to replace this:

```
first_link = soup.findAll('a', id=True, limit=img_limit)
for link in first_link:
```

With:

```
 from random import choice

 first_link = soup.findAll('a', id=True, limit=img_limit)
 link = choice(first_link)
```

This will select one random item from the list

Comment: You sir are a genius Thank you!